# BlackBerry - MainScreen with labels vertical scroll

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, label, scroll, mainscreen

I am trying to create a `MainScreen` with vertical scrolling. From what I've read in the documentation, `MainScreen` has a `VerticalManager` inside, so it should be possible to enable vertical scrolling only with proper construction, i.e:

```
super(MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLL | MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);
```

This is not working for me, however. I am creating a screen, adding a couple of `LabelField`s and no scrollbar, no scrolling at all. I am testing on 8900, OS 5.0.

Here is the code I use:

```
public class ExampleScreen extends MainScreen {

    public ExampleScreen() {
        super(MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLL | MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);
        create();
    }

    private void add(String text) {
        add(new LabelField(text));
    }

    private void create() {
        add("line 0");
        add("line 1");
        ...
        etc
        ...
    }
}
```

The question is am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to enable vertical scrolling with `MainScreen` or do I need to create a `VerticalManager` myself?

Comment: Main screen turn on. (I couldn't help myself ^^)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **LabelField**(s) added to the screen should either be **FOCUSABLE** themselves, or you can add the following BETWEEN each of the label fields: **add(new NullField(NullField.FOCUSABLE));**